# Cannot restore nuget packages on VSTS (Packages failed to install)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, continuous-integration, nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package-restore

I'm using Visual Studio Team Services to build a .NET solution. I have a `Nuget Installer` task to restore the packages of the solution that is configured as follows:

[image]

`Nuget.config` file has 2 package sources - one is [nuget.org (v2)](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/) and the other is a custom feed (Nuget Server v2.5.40416.9020). All packages from the nuget.org feed are restored but the ones from the custom feed are not, for each package from the custom feed there is an error message like this:

> Unable to find version 'abc' of package 'xyz'

Error:

> [error]Error:
>   C:\a_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.22\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\3.3.0\NuGet.exe
>   failed with return code: 1 [error]Packages failed to install

This was working fine 1 or 2 days ago.

Locally everything seems to work fine. Also, I tried with the nuget version 3.5.0 and a custom version of `nuget.exe`, without success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I had exactly the same problem like you today. But I put it the RC version of Nuget and it resolved my problem...

Comment: I can't reproduce that issue when restore package in the VSTS feed during the Nuget Restore build step. Share your detail build log on the OneDrive, we will check it.

Comment: Issue is now fixed... I didn't change anything!!!

Comment: @starain I have the same problem, this time with another build.

Comment: Do you mean pervious build works fine and just a build have this issue? What's the difference between build definition and projects? Share your detail build log on the OneDrive.

Comment: False alarm, sorry about that. After some debugging I realised that this time a developer deleted a nuget package on our private feed - that's why restoring the packages was failing on VSTS.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this error today. I fixed this error by reviewing the changes in my solution file with our base code branch and found some old lines that weren't supposed to be there. I think they were a result of a bad merge and should have been removed during a conflict resolve.

To fix the issue I simply removed the references that were old and everything built just fine.

```
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Services", "Services", "{EAECFF2D-7339-4180-8E1E-6DF9EC9EB131}"
EndProject
{3C14F190-6B6A-4913-9681-AFD9B62850FA} = {EAECFF2D-7339-4180-8E1E-6DF9EC9EB131}
{687ECE00-A567-40F3-BFF9-C3B639328F27} = {EAECFF2D-7339-4180-8E1E-6DF9EC9EB131}
```

Thanks,
Fissh